# Documenting the configuration of Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, configuration, documentation

Are there any tools that can be used to document configuration of Windows Server 2003?

By configuration I mean:

- Services installed
- Programs installed
- Users
- IIS config

**UPDATE1:**

Simplified instructions.  Extract zip to folder on server and then go to command line (cmd).

Exporting to Word format (need Word on the server):

```
cscript sydi-server.vbs
```

Exporting to XML format (you will need the XSL files in the XML subfolder):

```
cscript sydi-server.vbs -oFILENAME.xml -ex -sh
```

-ex (is for XML format)

-sh (formats XML)

-o (defines output filename)

** UPDATE2: **

To filter out any Windows Service that is disabled:

```
For Each objItem In colItems
'ignore any service that has a startMode of disabled
If objItem.StartMode <> "Disabled" Then
    'ok to add      
    objDbrServices.AddNew
    objDbrServices("Caption") = objItem.Caption
    objDbrServices("Started") = objItem.Started
    objDbrServices("StartMode") = objItem.StartMode 
    objDbrServices("StartName") = objItem.StartName
    If (LCase(objItem.Caption) = "mssqlserver") Then
         bRoleSQL = True
    End If
       objDbrServices.Update
End If
      Next
objDbrServices.Sort = "Caption"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sydiproject.com/ is a popular free tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Self promotion warning.

Also take a look at [Open-AudIT](http://www.open-audit.org).

Very similar to Sydi - several options for output of results and able to store results in a database. OAv2 is even better.

Answer (score 1):

Another self promotion warning.  Take a look at XIA Configuration, it can [document the configuration of Windows](http://www.centrel-solutions.com/XIAConfiguration/capabilities.aspx?capability=WindowsMachine&referrer=hssf), including Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008.  It includes support for the points you mention i.e. services and programs/software installed, users and IIS config.

There is a free version available for small networks:

http://www.centrel-solutions.com/XIAConfiguration/workgroupedition.aspx